# Vue JS Component calling functions in JS Files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am making a **Vue JS** project inside Laravel Project

how can I call data from other JS File?

what I have now is

**MainComponent.vue**

```
data() {
   return this.getData()
}
```

**DataComponent.js**

```
module.exports = {
     getData() {
        variable1: [],
        variable2: []
     }
};
```

i dont know if i do it correctly but maybe someone could help. Thank you!

Comment: Save data to vuex store and the grab it from other component

Comment: do you know how to do it? do i need to install vuex for it?

Comment: if you need that data to be available to whole app, they yes. You should use vuex as much you can even on simple things. If your DataComponent is child of MainComponent then you could pass the data via props input e.g <data-component [data]="data"></data-component>, add more info about how you want to use that data and why for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you're trying to do but maybe this will help:

MainComponent.vue

```
import { _data } from './DataComponent'
    data() {
       return _data
    }
```

DataComponent.js

```
export const _data = {
var1:[],
var2: []
}
```

Comment: Just be careful because Vue will make `_data` reactive, and thus mutate the variable. If you ever decide to re-use that variable elsewhere, just know that if you altered it in anyway from your component, the variable will reflect those mutations.

Comment: @webkit do we have another way to call it like `return this.getData()`

Comment: @Imperatura not sure what you're trying to do.. you can't do that in 'data' but maybe a computed value

Answer (score 0):

you must export js module then import inside Component for example

> Test.js

```
module.exports = {
     getData() {
        variable1: [],
        variable2: []
     }
};
```

> MyComponent.vue

```
import { obj } from 'your_js_file_path/Test'
```

then you can use forexamle inside some method

`obj.getData();`

Comment: i tried it just now but it returns error Syntax Error Unexpected token